# Auto refresh PDF of my docs in TexStudio

Tags: texstudio, editors, viewers

To be honest, I think that it is stupid question (sorry if duplicate). By the way, I worked a lot with Overleaf.com. They have amazing function to refresh pdf each time you make some changes in files.[image]

Of course, now, when I work with TexStudio, I think: "Hm, it would be great to have this opportunity here too!". I understand that for normal compiling I should save file literally every second and call compiler to make his job (and Overleaf somehow waits for the moment when you finish typing commands, i.e. its tries to compile are always compilable if I don't make mistakes).

The question is: may be somehow such opportunity is possible in TexStudio too?

PS. Personaly, I think I will dislike such feature. However, lets try this if possible.

I want it to work with embedded viewer of TexStudio.

Comment: This has been requested before: https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/366/. It's (to my knowledge) not inbuilt into the editor itself, so the short and quick answer is no. (Of course, if you refer to the link, there seems to be a script that you *could* use, but I have not tried it, nor is TeXstudio designed to do such a thing.) It seems too much of a bother to set it up anyway :p

Comment: Besides, once your document gets big, it could take several seconds to compile, so it's just going to be very heavy on your processor then, if you are trying to compile every time you type.

Comment: You can do this with `latexmk` (see https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk/). I don't use TexStudio, so I have no idea if it's possible to integrate `latexmk` with TexStudio or whether you would have to run it as a separate application.

Comment: @Troy it doesn't make much sense to "compile every time you type," because most of the time the document would be invalid (e.g you were half way through typing a macro name and its parameters) But it *does* make sense to compile automatically every time you *save* the document.

Comment: @alephzero Yup of course. Even then, my point still stands.

Comment: @Dida could you remove the chitchat and shorten your question to the facts, please?

Answer (score 1):

Have a small script in python which does the following:

```
import time
import os
while (True):
        os.system("xelatex yourOptionsHere youfile.tex")
        time.sleep(5)
```

But I can tell you, doing so sucks the processor !!